# Does gcloud sdk call google cloud REST API internally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-sdk

Would like to know if gcloud sdk will be invoking the REST APIs of google cloud internally? One of the root certificates used by the global sign root r2 is expiring soon. I am concerned if the old versions of gcloud sdk will be impacted due to this.

Comment: If the SDK is affected that would be a bug. Google has a method of reporting bugs: https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker Since that issue would affect millions of users, that bug would (should) be rapidly reported and then fixed. As @guillaume pointed out in his answer, you can see the HTTP conversation to perform your own tests and/or validation.

Answer (score 1):

When you use gcloud SDK, the public API of Google Cloud are called. You can view them by using the parameter `--log-http` at the end of your commands.

If your gcloud sdk is old; it could not work properly because of API updates. However, I don't see any relation with a root certificate.

Comment: I was concerned because  gcloud sdk may still be having the expired rootCA in its trusted CA bundle. But as long as the API servers that serve the google API are giving out the proper certs (without the expired root)  it should be OK.